# Can't add material to mesh

Tags: mesh, materials

Ok ... i just installed Blender today, watched some tutorials but i got stuck at this step because on none of the tutorials has this happened : 
when i select an object and i go into properties menu, under material, i have no + button to add a new one [image: material menu is empty]

Comment: scroll up on the properties window https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eHEo.gif

Answer (score 0):

nevermind, it was just me being dumb ... the button is there, i just needed to scroll up